# Convert Site Root Site Collection AND root of Web Application

Tags: 2010, migration, backup, restore

Greeting, everyone.

I've been getting my feet wet with SharePoint Consulting for the last couple of months now and I've been tasked with a migration that I wanted to run past this fine community.  Here's the task:

From within PowerShell, I am to research moving a sub site to a new location where it will be the root Site Collection in addition to residing at the root of the Web Application.  In case that didn't come out right, I'll try to break it down differently:

- Need to convert the sub site to a root Site Collection in a different Web Application

Example: From http://Contoso123.com/sites/blog_page3.aspx to  http://Contoso789.com/

- From what I have been reading, it seems that I should be able to use the Backup and Restore procedures.  I am concerned about issues with overlapping GUIDS, though, as I know that is a common pitfall in these scenarios.  I am also concerned with relative URL mappings, though I'm not 100% sure how to mitigate or even how to manually fix after the migration is done - or if this is even possible.

I hope this is clear enough.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Nathan

Comment: I have just the opposite problem. I need to convert my root site to the /sites path. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you looking is to move sites across managed paths.
Unfortunately there is not and easy way to change this without scripting (as far as I know)

Here is powershell script that this guy wrote

[Moving SharePoint 2010 Site Collections Between Managed Paths using PowerShell](http://jshidell.com/2012/06/26/moving-sharepoint-2010-site-collections-between-managed-paths-using-powershell/)

just make sure you backup before testing it :)

Hope this helps

Comment: This looks like information I had not come across yet - and quite pertinent to my question.  I have a couple hours until I head into the office but I'll give an update when I've had a chance to try this out.

Comment: I really appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem, good luck!